# How to create Multiple Project Collection in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to figure out how can one create multiple Project collections in visual Studio Online.

If that is not possible, If i create multiple accounts, can use the same MSDN subscriber across those project collection ?

Any links to document on how to achieve this is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported way to create multiple collections in VSO is to use multiple accounts. You can use your same MSDN subscription across all accounts and you can use the same AAD for single sign-on.

Comment: We have multiple collections in our plans - hopefully, later this year.

Comment: Also say we signed up extra users, will they be able to access multiple accounts with one license or will they need separate license for each account ?

Comment: MSDN licenses work across accounts. Monthly subscriptions (Basic, Pro, Advanced) are per account.

Comment: @BuckHodges better finish it soon before too many people follow this answer and create multiple accounts to get around this lack. Being used to on-prem, this is hard to swallow.

Comment: The way this has evolved is that we will support multiple collections by way of having the ability to group multiple accounts into an organizational tenant. A way to think of it is addressable collections (the address is the current account URL). The work is under way now.

Comment: Here is the UserVoice to vote for this: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3473653-let-us-create-multiple-collections-on-visual-studi